# Small question about scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm very new to lisp and recently i discovered the thin that I don't understand.

This code works:

```
(define (f x) (define a x) (define (b) a) (b))
```

And this doesn't:

```
(define (f x) (define a x) (define b a) b)
```

Why?

Comment: It works. Does your Scheme report some error?

Comment: Can somebody re-frame question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In kawa interpeter it works
In Guile it doesn't, because 
this code

```
(define (f x) (define a x) (define b a) b)
```

is expand to

```
(define (f x) (letrec ((a x) (b a)) b))
```

And you can't access to `a` before I's assign. `letrec` won't work for non-function definitions, for example:

```
(letrec ((x 5)
         (y x))
     y)
```

You can use `let*` insted

```
(define (f x) (let* ((a x) (b a)) b))
```

In this code

```
(define (f x) (define a x) (define (b) a) (b))
```

In procedure b you access a varible when it's already defined.

Comment: Two problems in this question: *Some* versions of `letrec`s won't work, not all (specifically, those that implement it as a `letrec*`).  Also, those that implement a stricter `letrec` won't allow using a bound name in one of the (other) expressions -- there is no Scheme implementation that restricts them only to functions.  (OTOH, ML does.)

Answer (score 2):

You should look up discussions about `letrec*` -- some implementations use it as a more permissive version of the stricter `letrec`, which results in the difference you see.

Answer (score 0):

You might be seeing the change in behavior between the R5RS and R6RS standards. One of the [changes in R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-19.html) is "Internal definitions are now defined in terms of `letrec*`."

In R5RS, the internal `define`s [are completely equivalent](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%25_sec_5.2.2) to a `letrec`. In particular, the section on internal definitions says that "Just as for the equivalent `letrec` expression, it must be possible to evaluate each `<expression>` of every internal definition in a `<body>` without assigning or referring to the value of any `<variable>` being defined."

However, in R6RS, internal `define`s [are equivalent](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.3) to a `letrec*`. And, as you would expect, `letrec*` [allows](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_406) you to refer to the value of preceding variables in the intializer for later variables.